# How to update Quicken on PC while leaving ON TrendMicro

Tags: anti-virus, quicken

Im on an HP Spectre laptop, Windows10 Home 20H2....  So about 1 year or so ago I tried to update quicken while keeping my TrendMicro AV on as usual and the update always failed.  Quicken downloads and attempts to apply the download, but then a quicken window pops up and says update has failed. 1st encounter with this issue.  I called Quicken and was told that the TrendMicro has to be turned off to download and install update.  So since then, I now always have to disable TrendMicro, download and install Quicken update then restart TrendMicro.

Question:  How can I leave on TrendMicro for the Quicken update download and install?
When downloading and installing programs/updates from the internet, isn't   this the time you want your virus protection on as not to be more vulnerable against virus, etc.?

Comment: I would start by creating an exception TrendMicro within for the installation directory of Quicken. If that still does not work, sounds like a known issue, so I would follow the advice you have received from Quicken.  Difficult to answer this question without knowing which version of Quicken you are running.

Comment: Quicken Deluxe, R36.23 , 27.1.36.23 Build.  This has been gong on since about the last 5 or so updates.

Comment: Quicken is Intuit. I have QuickBooks running here (Windows 10 Pro). Earlier versions of Windows I had Symantec Endpoint installed and new versions of Windows I depend solely on Windows Defender. You might try a full uninstall of Trend Micro (at least temporarily) and let Windows Defender take over. Restart and see if Quicken updates.

Comment: @Stumped - Have you attempted to create an exception for the installation directory within TrendMicro then perform the update?  Have you created an exception for the installer for the upgrade?  Can you provide any specific errors that happen?  Instead of submitting a comment vital information should be added to your question.

Comment: Thanks John. I thought Quicken was stand alone now having been spun off from Intuit.  But that is moot here I think.  I cannot try that yet as ive already done the most recent update by turning off trend micro, installing the quicken update and then turning it back on.  I can add Quicken to the TrendMicro program exception list and wait and see what happens during the next update.  But if I add it to the exception list, will TrendMicro still scan during the download&update?  TM support says yes

Comment: @Stumped - You can always manually downgrade Quicken.  Of course you would have to load a compatible version of your data if you did that.

Comment: so if I add Quicken to the TrendMicro Exception List, Quicken will no longer be monitored or scanned??  i.e., Trend Micro could then potentially allow virus to be downloaded and installed during a quicken update?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, I created an exception for Quicken inside the TrendMicro program.  Today when I started Quicken I got a notification of an update and I ok'd it and it was downloaded and applied with no issues as before.  However, I cannot verify wether or not is was scanned by TrendMicro due to the exception list.